# Coffeescript compiled to Node.js vs browser JS differences

Tags: coffeescript

What should I be careful to avoid in order for my CoffeeScript code to run on both Node.js and javascript? The obvious answer is "don't use Node.js" functions, but I was wondering if there are other minor "gotchas" that would break porting the code between the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you don't rely on any APIs beyond the language itself (e.g. you don't use any functions other than `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout` and `setInterval`/`clearInterval` and those attached to `Math`), there are just two things to worry about:

1. You can rely on newer JS features like `Array::forEach` and `Array::indexOf` being around in Node, but not in the browser. CoffeeScript helps you avoid these two gotchas with the `for x in arr` and `if x in arr` syntaxes, respectively.
2. In the browser, the global object is `window`; in Node, the global object is `global`, but you usually want to export things instead. So the usual solution, as demonstrated by [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html) and others, is to write `root = this` at the top of your module and attach everything to `root`. In the outermost scope, `this` points to `window` in browsers and `exports` in Node.

I'm assuming here that you're defining your module in a single script. If not, you should look at a tool like sstephenson's [stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch), which lets you write a set of modules that can `require` each other in Node, then "stitch" them together for browsers.

Comment: +1 for `root = this` -- despite the mighty Mr. Katz's [reassuring tone in this article](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/), if you do as Mr. Burnham says, your life will be much simpler in general.